# Setting UIButton title in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UiTableView` that I create and set a `UIButton` and it's title. Since the data comes from a web service = I do this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. The `Tableview` uses reusable cells due to the fact that cells often grow to over 100 or more. So it's a memory thing.

This is what my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

       cell.item = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];

    /* Add a button to the cell - for user name */
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [myButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    /* Setup the button */

    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(214, 5, 93, 21);
    [myButton setTitle:cell.item.userName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];


    return cell;
}
```

**Problem**

This works just fine. However as I start scrolling, `myButton`'s label is shows multiple values and looks like I have added multiple titles onto one button. I suspect the reason is due to cell reuse. The "new" cell that comes into view still has the "old" cell's `myButton`'s title.

**Question**

How do I avoid this without reverting to non-reusable cells?

Comment: are you creating cells with storyboard?

Comment: @Tander: I think that you have renamed your button from `sellerButton` to `myButton` for asking the question on Stackoverflow. However the renaming is incomplete making the code more difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks - edited the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added multiple titles to a button, in fact you have added multiple buttons. With

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

you create a completely new button and with

```
    [cell.contentView addSubview:sellerButton];
```

you add it to the cell as a subview. When the cell is created for the first time it will only have one button. But when the cell is reused it already has a button (or many) and another one is added on top. When the button's background is transparent it appears like a single button with multiple titles.

One way to solve this problem would be to check if the cell already *has* a button and in that case only change the button's title (e.g. by using tags as suggested in other replies).

A much better way would be to add the button in your custom cell's initializer method, create a property for the button in your custom cell's class and in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you only change the button's title.

**In MyCustomCell.h:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *sellerButton;
```

**In MyCustomCell.m:**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        /* Add a button to the cell - for user name */
        self.sellerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [self.sellerButton addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(buttonPressed:)                    
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        /* Setup the button */
        self.sellerButton.frame = CGRectMake(214, 5, 93, 21);
        [self.sellerButton setTitle:self.item.userName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.sellerButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**In your table view controller's .m file:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    cell.item = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    [cell.sellerButton setTitle:cell.item.userName forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

In my opinion this is a much cleaner approach than using tags to identify your button in the cell's view hierarchy as you separate the cell's layout configuration (that doesn't change) from the data it presents (the button title).

Comment: only view controllers have `viewDidLoad` method. Custom views are usually created in cell's designated initializer.

Comment: Thanks. I have done exactly this, however the button now doesn't show up at all on the cells.

Comment: Have you tried setting the frame to something like (0, 0, 100, 100)? Maybe it's just out of the cell's bounds and hence not visible?

Comment: Yes. The problem is self.sellerButton is nil at the time of setting its title. I put a breakpoint on the designated initialiser and its never called. The rest of the code in the sellerButton class works though. Any ideas?

Comment: I see. Then check the other initializer methods. It depends which one you use. E.g. there is also the `-initWithFrame:` or the `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. If you don't know which one is used by the table view I suggest you add some log statements to those methods.

Comment: To get around the issue in my setItem setter method in the cell's custom class I call a separate method to setup the cell's button. This works fine. Is it an acceptable way of doing things? I'll try log init methods now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: One last thing: I have put the buttons selector method in its class. I need the method to push a new view controller onto the stack. Do I need to use a delegate that is called in the viewController my UitableView exists in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56901/discussion-between-tander-and-mischa).

Comment: One more thing: If you create your custom cell with the storyboard anyway I suggest you add the button to the cell in the storyboard as well and create an `IBAction` for it. You don't need to do this programmatically and you won't have to worry about the initializer method.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help you prevent duplicating the `UIButton` objects

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    cell.item = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];

    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    if (myButton) {
        //button already present
        NSLog(@"Button already present");
    }
    else {
        //button not present
        myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton setTag:100];  //needed for this logic to work
        [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(214, 5, 93, 21)];
        [myButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
    }

    [myButton setTitle:cell.item.userName forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This actually helped me with my UIButton. Since I created my button in storyboard, I checked to see if my button's current title was nil. If so then I did all my label updating, otherwise I left it alone... and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @KingPolygon : You're welcome but if you created your button in a custom `UITableViewCell` via storyboard then you don't need to do any of this. Just create an `IBOutlet` for your button in the custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, connect it through the storyboard and access it directly with `cell.myButton`.

Comment: Thanks @staticVoidMan! I was referring to the part that checks of the Button is already present. :)

Comment: @KingPolygon : oh. ok then :P